# Magento 2.3.5 - Change all attributes to searchable no by scrip

Tags: magento2.3, attributes

Is there a way, maybe by using a script, to set the searchable value of all attributes to no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was possible to do it by sql directly. But for the sake of scalability, I decided to create a small module that does enable you to update all your product attributes with a fixed given value.

It goes without saying this module is not really viable but hopefully I might improve it somewhat.

https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/productattributeupdate/src/master/

Please do backup your database before using the module

and then run once the module is installed, run the command `php bin/magento mbs:attributes:update is_searchable 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works amazing and a very good method to also implement other attributes.